# Upscaling cold drip type setup

Tags: cold-brew

Just wondering if anyone here has upscaled a cold drip type setup to yield 30 odd liters

Aiming for a ratio of 1:7.5 coffee to water

Plan was the make a type of recirculating system which would be like a mix of cold brew and drip or to make it a one pass system with a spray nozzle

Anyone tried a recirculating system ? Wanted to know before I potentially waste 4 kg worth of beans

Comment: Did you check https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/4305/how-can-i-maximize-cold-brew-yield-without-harming-flavor ?

Comment: And maybe this: https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/4542/how-to-make-50litre-of-cold-coffee-from-ground-coffee